Браузер перестал отображать css элементы
Заканчиваю свой первый проект на django (не коммерческий, а обучения ради). Осталось только дописать небольшую часть и привести код в порядок. Начал со второго и не совсем понял, в который именно момент, словил проблему: браузер Firefox 132.0.2 без видимых мне причин (хотя возможно обновился в процессе) перестал отображать большинство css элементов. При этом нет никаких ошибок. Хромиум (Version 129.0.6668.100 (Official Build) snap (64-bit) ) работает по-прежнему корректно.
Для теста установил Opera (114.0.5282.185) - она как и Фвйрфокс - не видит owl-carousel, banner-text и другое.
Дизайн сайта заимствовал у Media.center, капитально перелопатил под себя, потратил на все почти два месяца жизни, потому как большинство вещей пришлось делать впервые и учиться на ходу. И получил такой удар под дых.
Для проверки создал полностью новый проект, в который добавил только первую страницу своего сайта. Там все так же непонятно: Хромиум работает корректно, а Файрфокс и Опера - слепые как и в случае с проектом. Из фрагментов кода сюда кину разве что подгрузку css и js:
{% load static %}

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">

        <!-- Customizable CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/style.css' %}">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/rtl.css' %}">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/colors/navy.css' %}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/owl.carousel.css' %}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/owl.transitions.css' %}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/animate.min.css' %}">

        <!-- Project_custom -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/project_custom.css' %}">

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

        <!-- Icons/Glyphs -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/font-awesome.min.css' %}">

        <!-- Favicon -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'assets/images/favicon.ico' %}">

        <!-- HTML5 elements and media queries Support for IE8 : HTML5 shim and Respond.js -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="{% static 'assets/js/html5shiv.js' %}"></script>
            <script src="{% static 'assets/js/respond.min.js' %}"></script>
        <![endif]-->

        <!--        SITEAJAX-->
                {% include "siteajax/cdn.html" %}

и:
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDDZJO4F0d17RnFoi1F2qtw4wn6Wcaqxao&sensor=false&amp;language=en"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/gmap3.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/css_browser_selector.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/echo.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/jquery.easing-1.3.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/bootstrap-slider.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/jquery.raty.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/jquery.customSelect.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/wow.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/buttons.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/scripts.js' %}"></script>

<script src="{% static 'assets/js/category-filter.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/store-slider.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/user-buttons.js' %}"></script>

Так должна выглядеть верхняя часть стартовой страницы и так ее видит Хромиум:

Так не должно быть, но так с недавних пор ее стали отображать Файрфокс и Опера

Прилагаю ссылку на скачивание всего проекта на django. Внутри json файл для заполнения бд. Подскажите, что это за проблему, или намекните, на что или кого грешить. Если нет очевидного ответа, буду очень благодарен просто за тест на своих ос и браузерах.
скачать проект

Из скриншотов видно, что CSS в порядке, а вот изображения не подгружаются.

если картинки должны грузиться с отдельного домена или даже поддомена, убедитесь что на нём работает https, либо попробуйте отключить в настройках режим "только https во всех окнах".

Да в том-то и дело, что настройки media месяц как неизменны. Пока все прописано в settings как
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
